# How do I detect where my mouse is while holding a mouse button in a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing

As the title says I want to know where my program to know where my mouse is while I'm holding a mouse button and moving it around the JFrame. I could only find a way to detect after I stop holding the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the method MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation() - it returns a Point object corresponding to current mouse position.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Add a MouseEventListener to your Button or JFrame. The based on event either MousePress or MouseClick, you can get position event.getX() or event.getY()

```
 public class MouseEventDemo implements MouseListener {


  //Register for mouse events on button or frame      
  yourButton.addMouseListener(this);

   ...

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { 


      saySomething("Mouse pressed; # of clicks: " + e.getX(), e); 


    }
   }
```